# Reindex after change in one field

Tags: solr

I have a field with indexed="no" and stored="yes" and now I need to query that field.

How can build this index after setting indexed="yes"? or I need to do a complete reindex (re-import) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll need to do a complete reindex. Solr indexes a document at a time and in order to have any change done to any of its fields, the whole document will have to be reindexed.

If *all* your fields are `stored`, you might be able to write some code to have the complete reindexing done without having to fetch the data again from the data source -- you can fetch the documents from Solr and then add them back to Solr.